# Infragistics XamChart databinding

Tags: data-binding, infragistics, pie-chart

I have a total number of experiments, each can be in on of 6 states. I'd like to present this data as a pie chart using XamChart.
How can I bind the number of experiments in state X to a part of the pie? The Feature Browser isn't much help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was binding the value to the numeric value. To show those numbers in the built-in legend I used the label, but my databinding was to a string that was concatenated like this:

```
string RuningLabel = `"Running, " + NumRunning`;
```

XAML:

```
 <igCa:XamChart.Series>
                    <igCa:Series ChartType="Pie">
                        <igCa:Series.DataPoints>
                            <igCa:DataPoint Value="{Binding ActivityStatus.NumWaiting}" Label="{Binding Path=InfoHelper.WaitingLabel}" Fill="Yellow"/>
                            <igCa:DataPoint Value="{Binding ActivityStatus.NumAssigned}" Label="{Binding Path=InfoHelper.AssignedLabel}" Fill="LightPink"/>
                            <igCa:DataPoint Value="{Binding ActivityStatus.NumRunning}" Label="{Binding InfoHelper.RunningLabel}" Fill="Orange"/>
                            <igCa:DataPoint Value="{Binding ActivityStatus.NumPassed}" Label="{Binding InfoHelper.PassedLabel}" Fill="Green"/>
                            <igCa:DataPoint Value="{Binding ActivityStatus.NumFailed}" Label="{Binding Path=InfoHelper.FailedLabel}" Fill="DarkRed"/>
                            <igCa:DataPoint Value="{Binding ActivityStatus.NumOnHold}" Label="{Binding InfoHelper.OnholdLabel}" Fill="DarkGray"/>
                            <igCa:DataPoint Value="{Binding ActivityStatus.NumRemoved}" Label="{Binding InfoHelper.RemovedLabel}" Fill="LightBlue"/>
                            <igCa:DataPoint Value="{Binding ActivityStatus.NumStopped}" Label="{Binding InfoHelper.StoppedLabel}" Fill="CornflowerBlue"/>
                            <igCa:DataPoint Value="{Binding ActivityStatus.NumStuck}" Label="{Binding InfoHelper.StuckLabel}" Fill="DarkKhaki"/>
                        </igCa:Series.DataPoints>
                    </igCa:Series>
                </igCa:XamChart.Series>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a list that has the states and values for those states and then you would use that as the data source for a series.  The following is a simple example using a DataTable:

```
void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Series s = new Series()
    {
        DataSource = TestData(5).DefaultView,
        DataMapping = "Value = Col_3; Label = Col_1",
        ChartType = ChartType.Pie,
        Label = "Series 1"
    };
    this.xamChart1.Series.Add(s);
}

private DataTable TestData(int rows)
{
    DataTable dtData = new DataTable("TestData");

    dtData.Columns.Add("Col_1", typeof(string));
    dtData.Columns.Add("Col_3", typeof(int));

    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtData.NewRow();

        dr["Col_1"] = "Row " + i.ToString();
        dr["Col_3"] = i;

        dtData.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dtData;
}
```

The DataMapping property is what determines what the values and the Labels are.  For this example the XamChart was created in XAML with the following markup:

```
<igCA:XamChart Name="xamChart1"/>
```